# is it safe to use Model::unguard();?

Tags: php, laravel

Is it safe to use Model::unguard(); other than $fillable ?

For example, I want to keep the model unguarded and not use the fillable. It seems like unguard does the same thing as fillable. I want to know if it is secure and safe from SQL injection and other issues to use it like that.

Comment: has nothing to do with SQL injection, that is handled by the prepared statements that Eloquent uses (via query builder) ... you are just leaving the model open to be filled with any attributes (via mass assignment) that is all, you will have to make sure when filling the model that you only give it attributes that you actually have fields for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about mass assignment vulnerabilities. And you can look at the example of mass assignment vulnerability on https://ropesec.com/articles/mass-assignment/. It's actually depends on what you want to store on db.

Answer (score 0):

There is mass assignment vulnerabilities, but what I do to circumvent this is to specify which fields I will be updating in my update/insert queries like this:

```
$table->create([
'company_id' => companyid(),
'name' => $name,
]);
```

This is similar to assigning the fields in the model, but much more robust since you can set it per query instead of at the model level where arguably you would still have mass assignment vulnerability if you decided to allow a sensitive field to be edited down the road in your model (by a site admin for instance), and put that in the model to do so. By setting it at the query level, you can leave it completely open (model::unguard), and then only specify what can be updated/inserted in your query, while also performing other checks (like is_admin checks)

Answer (score 0):

Using Model::unguard(); and not using $fillable in your Laravel model means you are disabling the mass assignment protection. While this can be convenient for development purposes, it is generally not recommended for production environments, as it increases the risk of security vulnerabilities such as SQL injection attacks.

To ensure the security of your application, it is better to use the $fillable property to explicitly define the attributes that can be mass-assigned. This way, you can have more control over the data being saved to your database and prevent unauthorized modifications.